# Flutter move row within column to the bottom of the page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a footer at the bottom of the page using SizedBox however I am having issues positioning it correctly.

I am using the following layout:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child:Column(
    children: [
      Center(),
      Center(),
      Spacer(),
      SizedBox()
    ]
  )
)
```

When I try to run it I get a renderflex error, after doing some searching around I saw people mention that i should wrap my column in Expanded or SizedBox however both of those do not work as they also give renderflex error's on their own. I also tried using align combined with mainAxisAlignment but that doesn't move anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also show the parent of this SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: The problem is because you made it a Scrollview there is an infinite amount of space. The Scrollview's child can be as tall as it wants. Therefore you can't use any Spacer there because a Spacer takes "all the available space" which there is infinite of

Comment: Ah I understand column inside a scrollview has no limit, ok gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `scaffold`, there is an option called `bottomSheet` , it exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
body:Stack(
 children: [
 SingleChildScrollView(
  child:Column(
    children: [
        Center(),
        Center(),
        Spacer(),
       ]
     ),
   )`
   Positioned (
        bottom:0, 
        child:SizedBox(),
   )
 ]
),
```